# iPad: Have child navbar be a different color than the main navbar

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

We are currently working on and ipad app that has a navigation controller. When we tap a button and open a second view - the view inherits the main navigation controller. We want to be able to set the second navigation controllers color.

We are using UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [CustomNavigationController.self]) to change the color.
See screen shot.

Hierarchy:
View loads -> Segue to add in the side bar(buttons view) -> Tap a button -> Opens a secondary view and passes in the navcontroller.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `viewWillAppear` method of the view controller you can set the nav bar's `tintColor`. In `viewWillDisappear` you can reset the `tintColor` to its previous color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This seems to only work when you open the view a second/third time and not the first.

Comment: You really need to update your question with relevant code so people can help you find the issue.

Comment: I misread your answer and did something wrong. We weren't using completed UI yet on those secondary views. Had to add in viewWillAppears.